# Error in Python Program in Subproces.Popen

Tags: python, perl, nltk

I have written following Python program which includes wrapper function lesk_similarity to compute similarity score using Perl program. GetMAxSim function returns max similarity score from number of combinations from both the synstes.

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
import subprocess

def lesk_similarity(a,b):
    cmd = ['perl','./sample.pl',a,b]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
    for line in proc.stdout:
        if 'Similarity' in line:
            similarity = int(line.split('=')[-1])
    return similarity

def getMaxSim(synsets1, synsets2):
    maxSim = None
    for s1 in synsets1:
        for s2 in synsets2:
            sim = lesk_similarity(s1,s2)
            if maxSim == None or maxSim < sim:
                maxSim = sim
                s3 = s1
                s4 = s2

    print s3.definition
    print s4.definition
    return maxSi

ChurchSynsets = wordnet.synsets("church", pos="n")
TempleSynsets = wordnet.synsets("temple", pos="n")
print "create<>make:", getMaxSim(ChurchSynsets, TempleSynsets)
```

churchSynset and Templesynset contains following data:

churchsynset[Synset('church.n.01'),Synset('church.n.02'),Synset('church_service.n.01'),  Synset('church.n.04')]
temple synset [Synset('temple.n.01'), Synset('temple.n.02'), Synset('temple.n.03'), Synset('synagogue.n.01')]

I am getting following error after running this code:

```
madhusudan@maddy:~/WordNet-Similarity-2.05/samples$ python test4.py
create<>make:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test4.py", line 40, in <module>
    print "create<>make:", getMaxSim(ChurchSynsets, TempleSynsets)
  File "test4.py", line 17, in getMaxSim
    sim = lesk_similarity(s1,s2)
  File "test4.py", line 7, in lesk_similarity
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: `a` and `b` must be strings, as the error message tells you. `CurchSynsets` and `TempleSynsets` which you provide as `a` and `b` obviously aren't strings. So...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this line
    cmd = ['perl','./sample.pl',a,b]

To 
    cmd = ['perl','./sample.pl', str(a), str(b)]